# Ожидание возникновения события в заданном промежутке времени

Tags: c#

Предположим есть следующие классы в приложении:

```
public class MessageSentEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public MessageSentEventArgs(int index)
    {
        this.Index = index;
    }
    public int Index {get; private set;}
}

public delegate void MessageSentEventHandler(object sender, MessageSentEventArgs e)

public class Message
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? Index {get; private set;}
    public MessageDirection Direction {get;set;}

    //обработчик события Сообщение успешно отправлено
    public void Sent(object sender, MessageSentEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Index = e.Index;
    }
}

    public void SendingMessage(string phone, string message)
    {
        var messages = context.Messages
            .Where(x=>x.Index==null&&x.Direction==MessageDirection.Out)
            .ToList();
        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            this.MessageSent += message.Sent;
            ExecuteCommand("AT+CMGS=" + msg.Length);
            ExecuteCommand(msg.ToString()+(char)26);
            //вот здесь я хочу приостановить программу
            //до тех пор пока не сработает событие либо
            //истечет интервал времени
        }
    }       
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как приостановить дальнейшее выполнение программы до тех пор пока не произойдет событие *MessageSent* либо истечет определенные интервал времени

**UPD:**
внес следующие изменения:

```
public delegate void MessageSentEventHandler(object sender, DbContext context, MessageSentEventArgs e)
public void Sent(object sender, DbContext context, MessageSentEventArgs e)
{
    this.Index = e.Index;
    context.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

но тут меня ждал большой облом, всем строкам входящим в коллекцию `messages` присваивается последний `index`. Есть подозрения что это делается как то просто, вот только я не знаю как

Comment: В какой момент вы хотите приостановить выполнение? После вызова метода `SendingMessage`?

Comment: @andreycha давайте я уточню некоторые моменты [здесь](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29932/discussion-for-http-ru-stackoverflow-com-questions-456201)

Comment: @Bald56rus, все уточнения должны быть в самом вопросе. Учитесь формулировать мысли четко.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быстрое исправление на ваш Update: отправляйте только одно сообщение, а не сразу все (уберите цикл). После получения события `MessageSent` лезьте в базу и отправляйте следующее сообщение.

Проблема в вашем текущем коде в том, что первое же событие `MessageSent` отрабатывает сразу у всех сообщений - просто потому что это общее на них на всех событие.

---

Теперь про исходную задачу.

Ожидать события можно двумя способами: синхронно и асинхронно.

Синхронное ожидание:

```
MessageSentEventArgs WaitForMessageSent() {
    MessageSentEventArgs result = null;
    MessageSentEventHandler handler;

    using (var mre = new ManualResetEvent()) {

      handler = (o, e) => {
        MessageSent -= handler;
        result = e;
        try { mre.Signal(); } catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
      };
      MessageSent += handler;
      mre.WaitOne();
      return result;

    }
}
```

Асинхронное ожидание:

```
Task<MessageSentEventArgs> WaitForMessageSent() {
    var result = new TaskCompletionSource<MessageSentEventArgs>();
    MessageSentEventHandler handler;

    handler = (o, e) => {
      result.TrySetValue(e);
      MessageSent -= handler;
    };
    MessageSent += handler;

    return result.Task;
}
```

Вам, скорее всего, будет проще с первым вариантом. Второй вариант пригодится, если понадобится дождаться события не занимая при этом потока UI.

Но, в любом случае, помните про проблему, с которой вы столкнулись. Не пытайтесь дождаться сразу двух событий параллельно - первое же пришедшее событие пробудит оба "ожидателя".

Comment: Синхронное ожидание вызывает вопросы. Разве mre.WaitOne не заблокирует поток таким образом, что вызов события MessageSent не будет возможен?

Comment: @Geslot так для того, чтобы один поток ждал, пока не сработает событие, в любом случае потребуется второй поток, в котором это событие будет запущено.

Comment: @Geslot если приглядеться к коду - то станет видно, что событие возникает при чтении данных из COM-порта (вероятно, это виртуальный последовательтый порт, эмулируемый usb-gsm-модемом). А COM-порт всегда требует отдельного потока для чтения. Так что конкретно в этом случае синхронный вариант к взаимоблокировке не приведет.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу @Pavel Mayorov:

Я бы не рекомендовал синхронное ожидание, а сразу пользовался идеологически правильным асинхронным.

```
async Task<MessageSentEventArgs> MessageSentOrTimeout(TimeSpan ts)
{
    MessageSentEventHandler h = null;
    try
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MessageSentEventArgs>();
        h = (o, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args);
        MessageSent += h;
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(ts);
        var winner = await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, timeoutTask);
        if (winner == timeoutTask)
            throw new TimeoutException();
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        MessageSent -= h;
    }
}
```

Или даже так:

```
async Task<MessageSentEventArgs> MessageSentOrTimeoutWithCancellation(
            TimeSpan ts, CancellationToken ct)
{
    MessageSentEventHandler h = null;
    try
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MessageSentEventArgs>();
        h = (o, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args);
        using (ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled()))
        {
            MessageSent += h;
            var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(ts);
            var winner = await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, timeoutTask);
            if (winner == timeoutTask)
                throw new TimeoutException();
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        MessageSent -= h;
    }
}
```

---

Использовать как-то так:

```
public async Task SendingMessage(string phone, string message)
{
    // .....
    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        // запускаем ожидание уже здесь, чтобы избежать race condition:
        // сообщение может в принципе прийти и до await'а
        var sent = MessageSentOrTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
        ExecuteCommand("AT+CMGS=" + msg.Length);
        ExecuteCommand(msg.ToString() + (char)26);
        try
        {
            // дожидаемся здесь
            MessageSentEventArgs args = await sent;
            // обработать успех
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            // обработать таймаут
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет смысла передавать в один и тот же метод и токен отмены, и тайм-аут - достаточно одного токена.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Эти просто удобство. Ну и автор явно хотел таймаут. Да, можно из токена и таймаута сделать один супертокен (`var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(ct); cts.Token.CancelAfter(ts))`), но для этого тогда уж нужно писать библиотечный метод.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну и удобнее получить разные исключения для случая таймаута и отмены всей операции.

Comment: а можно Вас попросить пример кода как это будет вызываться, и где должно вызваться. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Bald56rus: Дописал в ответ.